# how to make short code working in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to add short code in my code. Here its is

```
function my_shortcode_functionnn() 
{ 
        $i = 'Hiii ';
        return $i;
} 
add_shortcode('myshortcodeee', 'my_shortcode_functionnn');
```

Then I have used it like this

```
<h1>options <?php $sc='[myshortcodeee]'; echo $sc; ?></h1>
```

Also I tried like this

```
<h1>options [myshortcodeee]</h1>
```

but in my output it shows `options [myshortcodeee]` instead of `options Hiii`

So what is the problem I don't know. Help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the function `do_shortcode()` so that the code make action:

```
<h1>options <?php echo do_shortcode('[myshortcodeee]'); ?></h1>
```